# accessing li's rel value when hovered within ul with id mainmenu3

Tags: jquery, html, css

im creating a 2 level jquery menu that when a list element is hovered upon a div is shown with a name matching the li's rel="divname" value

i have been matching it using the following code

```
$this.find(">li").hover().attr('rel');
```

but how do i only access the first level of li's that fall within  using this jquery code if i have the following html?

```
<ul class="Menu" id="mainmenu3">
        <li rel="accounts"><a href="/admin/users">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <li rel="analytics"> <a href="/admin/analytics">ANALYTICS</a></li>
        <li rel="tags"><a href="tags">TAGS</a></li>
        <li rel="settings"><a href="/admin/settings">SETTINGS</a></li>
        <li rel="logout"><a href="login/logout">LOGOUT</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to only target the first level of `<li>`'s when you bind your mouseover event:

```
$('#mainmenu3 > li').mouseover(function(){    
    $('div').text($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TjDX3/) of it working.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$this.children('li').hover().attr('rel')
```

However, this will give you the 'rel' attr of the first child only.